# Backslash and singe quote clarification in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, escaping, postgresql-9.4

I create a trigger something like this:

```
info := info || 'update\n'; // is this real newline character?
query := 'INSERT INTO log_table(record_id,info) VALUES(' || OLD.id || 
   ',' || quote_literal(info) || ')';
EXECUTE query
```

When I execute the trigger and get the result:

```
 id | record_id |            date            |   info   |                                                                        
----+-----------+----------------------------+----------$
  1 |       791 | 2015-03-24 10:31:35.188261 | update\n |
```

Does it mean the `\n` part is a real newline character? or a backslash (`\`) and a `n` character literally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I see, it's a literal backslash and character `n`.

We should use `E'\n'` to insert newline character.